# How to setup 3G modem in OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt, modem, 3g

OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05.1. USB dongle ZTE MF190.
I executed some installation commands from [this](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/3gdongle) tutorial. Now `dmesg | grep usb` shows me the following:

```
[    4.150000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    4.160000] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    4.160000] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    4.560000] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-platform
[   12.520000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   12.530000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   12.530000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   12.800000] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[   12.800000] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
```

As I understand, the modem is detected by OS and corresponding kernel module was loaded. But! There is no '/dev/ttyUSBX' devices. How to obtain the device file?

Comment: OpenWRT has very stripped down kernels...

Comment: So what should I do? The router has damaged WAN port, that's why I installed OpenWRT.

Comment: See the *Required Packages* on the tuto linked on your question , create a `/etc/modules.d/60-usb-serial` with the following line :`usbserial vendor=0x12d1 product=0x1003 maxSize=2048` , Use the `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` command to get the vendor ID and the Product ID. Then reboot.

Comment: setup a separate VLAN for the one ethernet port of the switch and use it for the Internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with 'ROOTer Golden Orb' mod of OpenWRT. It works 'out of box'.